# Failed run Radian after installation (improved console for R)

Tags: python, r, pip, console

I've installed radian package for R using python and its pip.

```
pip install radian
```

when I tried to run radian

```
radian
```

I obtained an error: **'RuntimeError: cannot determine R HOME'**
I use Windows 10 and VS Code.
R was installed with defaults.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to check if you add `radian` to your Windows system path. If you have not yet done so, you can use the following line of code in Windows PowerShell:

```
$Env:Path += ";C:\PATH\TO\RADIAN\FOLDER"
```

(Adjust the file path accordingly. The `;` ensures the path to be added after the current Path.)

The problem with your error is `radian` can't find the `R.exe` in your system. So you should also check if R.exe is in the system path. If not, you could use a similar command in Windows Powershell.

```
$Env:Path += ";C:\PATH\TO\R.EXE"
```

(Adjust the file path accordingly.)

Then, `radian` should be able to find `R.exe` and determine the R_HOME automatically.